# unable to send and receive Broadcast from activity :android

Tags: android

I am unable to send a Broadcast from one activity to other activity please see the code below. There are two buttons one for send Broadcast and other is for receiving Broadcast. I have tried following code. But my Receiver activity is running only when I click on checkBrodcast button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                   
    sendBrodcast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_brodcast);
    checkBrodcast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_brodcast);

        sendBrodcast.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.w("Check", "inside send broadcast");
                Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                broadcast.setAction("BROADCAST_ACTION");
                broadcast.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                sendBroadcast(broadcast);

            }
    });


    checkBrodcast.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class); 
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });

 }  
}
```

public class Receiver extends Activity {

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.w("Check", "Inside On Receiver");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("BROADCAST_ACTION");
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(br, filter);


}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     unregisterReceiver(br);
}
```

}

Comment: Because you have defined it inside an onclicklistener

Answer (score 1):

The way you have Initiated the BroadCast is fine. You just need to change the way you intercept this Broadcast.

**INITIATE A BROADCAST**

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                broadcast.setAction("BROADCAST_ACTION");
                broadcast.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

**INTERCEPT IT**

A) CREATE A RECEIVER

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.w("Check", "Inside On Receiver");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   };
```

B) REGISTER RECEIVER - Do this onCreate Activity Call Back

registerReceiver(br , new IntentFilter("BROADCAST_ACTION"));

Broadcast receivers registered this way(SINGLETON DECLARATION and NOT IN MANIFEST) - do not receive broadcasts unless the containing app is running. But as in your case you are firing a broadcast message onClick event, so the the app must be running. So I guess it is safe to assume that your receiver set up using this method, will work fine - *provided* **the class in which you declared your receiver is created and exists in the activity stack, before you fire  a broadcast from a different activity.**

Comment: Follow the steps/code mentioned in INTERCEPT IT, on your click listener.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not declaring your broadcast receiver in your Android Manifest.  Dynamically registered receivers well not receive broadcasts unless the containing app is running.

If you want the second activity to get the broadcasts without having to click the button to start the app, then add the appropriate broadcast receiver to the second activities android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to broadcast data from one activity to another, simply make use of Intent. In the light of your case simply call `finish()` in your `onClickListener()` and then in the `onDestroy` method of your second activity create Intent object and broadcast data as intent extra then, use `intent.getExtra()` method on `onReceive()` method of your `broadcastReceiver` class.

For more details:
[follow this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqU97bQ54B4)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your manifest. You have to register your receiver in your Manifest like this:

```
    <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.mybroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But anyway, personally, I don't like how you are building the broadcast receiver structure.
You should create a class that extendes from BroadcastReceiver like:

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
 {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Your receiver!!!!.",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } 
 }
```

Dont forget to set up your manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

And now the class from you are calling:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }

 public void startAlert(View view) 
 {    
     int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent =         
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

 }
```

}

Something like that!!!